# Create PDF file from emails

Tags: automation, zapier, zapier-cli

I am trying to create a zap where if an email with a certain subject string is sent to me, it automatically saves the body as a file in a specific folder. I could do all of this but I need those files to be in PDF format. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Last I looked a few months ago, I couldn't find a free convert to PDF function, but there are a few paid subscription apps that would create and return PDFs using the email body.

Search "pdf" on https://zapier.com/apps and you'll see a bunch of options.

Answer (score 0):

If the email is in HTML you can pass the body_HTML field to Cloud Convert. Then use Capture a Website to convert it to a PDF. [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brtHa.png)